# ASP.NET Project stopped working after updating to VS2017: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.NET project that worked perfectly in my previous Windows installation with VS2015.

I've clean installed Windows, VS2017, and cloned the git repo. Restored NuGet packages and started to get the following error on one of my 3 web projects:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Interestingly, I'm only getting this error on one of the 3 web projects while the others run just fine.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you targeting the correct framework version?

Comment: @STLDeveloper yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I've realized that there were many dependent assembly redirections. I've removed all of them, explicitly added `System.Runtime.InteropServices` as a package, and the problem was solved.

I have no idea why it was the case in the first place though.